# Custom Javascript scrolling plugin not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, plugins

Documentation: http://idiotwu.github.io/smooth-scrollbar/

Github: https://github.com/idiotWu/smooth-scrollbar

[My JSFiddle attempt](https://jsfiddle.net/BradMitchell/8vw2pexa/1/)

What am I missing or not doing correctly?

```
<div class="box" data-scrollbar="true">
<p>
 This is some sample text to input into the textbox on this Fiddle. This is some sample text to input into the textbox on this Fiddle......
 </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You tried to use the plugin before it was even declared.
I moved the usage part down and it worked.

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/8vw2pexa/2.

```
/* SMOOTH SCROLLING PLUGIN */
... plugin code ...

const { Scrollbar } = window;
Scrollbar.initAll({ speed: 0.15 });
```